# Must I close a prepared statement before or after I used the result in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Must I close the stmt statement before using the result:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM families WHERE famname = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $e);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->close(); //closing statement before using $result
return mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Or after using it:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM families WHERE famname = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $e);
$result = $stmt->execute();
return mysqli_num_rows($result);
$stmt->close(); //closing statement after using $result
```

Wich one is safer and will both work and wich one will you suggest to use.

**AFTER** *or* **BEFORE**

Comment: first option is correct.

Comment: Neither, actually. Both statements would never work. You need to learn regular mysqli syntax **BEFORE** trying it in complex statements.

Comment: No to mention that you should never select all the records only to count them.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Why wouldn't one of them work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `return`, the function will not continue to run statements after that, so anything you have after a `return` statement is seen will do nothing.

The first option is therefore the only valid one, and the second one is equal to a piece of code without any close statement.

Answer (score 2):

first option is correct. if you return then below lines of return statement will not executed.

So

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM families WHERE famname = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $e);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->close(); //closing statement before using $result
return mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

this will close `$stmt` and return data.

Your second option:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM families WHERE famname = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $e);
$result = $stmt->execute();
return mysqli_num_rows($result);
$stmt->close(); //closing statement after using $result
```

it will never execute  `$stmt->close();`  since it return before executing it.

Comment: Can any one explain me why it is downvoted?